# SQL Query not working properly after migrating to Sql Express from sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012-express

I was working on a database in sql server 2008 and all my queries were working but now we have shifted the database to sql express 2012. 
Now some of my queries are working whereas some are throwing error

Example:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,TIME_OF_DAY) FROM dbname.T1
```

> Query1 error: Cannot convert string to datetime.

Now if I `select *` from dbname.T1 and replace the * with `DATEPART(HOUR,TIME_OF_DAY)` it is working.

The only difference is Initially it is using SQLEXPRESS.dbname and when it runs it is using SQLEXPRESS.master

I don't understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a problem that appears after the 1000 rows.

Comment: No it's not..... edited the question